# jquery on click event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my click event

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul.notifi', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log('clicked');
  alert(id);
});
```

This is how I create those elements with the notifi class

```
$.each(response['notifResult'], function( index, value ) {
            $('.notifMenu').append('<li><a href="#"><i data-id="' + value['id'] + '" class="' + value['icon'] + ' text-purple notifi"></i> ' + value['notificationText'] + '</a></li>');
          });
```

This is where they are displayed

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have <span class="notifNumberRep">...</span> notifications</li>
              <li class="header">Click notifications to mark them as readed.</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu notifMenu">

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: your html class is `notifMenu` and your selector is `ul.notifi`???

Comment: Is your `.notifi` class exclusive to your `<li>` elements? If so take away the `ul` part from your class

Comment: use `i.notify` in place of `ul.notify`

Comment: Please add an example, this is not your full code. Its not even possible currently to edit your question to make it more presentable to readers.

Comment: @Lixus Did this and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `ul` of your delegated selector - the `notifi` class is on the `i` tag:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.notifi', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log('clicked');
  alert(id);
});
```

If you are wanting to fire the event on the click of the anchor or li, move the class and data attribute to the corresponding element

For example if you want the li to fire the above event:

```
$('.notifMenu').append('<li data-id="' + value['id'] + '" class="notifi"><a href="#"><i class="' + value['icon'] + ' text-purple"></i> ' + value['notificationText'] + '</a></li>');
```

However, I would bind it to your anchor as then you can prevent the default action of the anchor (which is probably going to take you off to another page).  Change your event binding to:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.notifi', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the ddefault action of the anchor so the following will be processed

  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log('clicked');
  alert(id);
});


// add data and class to anchor
$.each(response['notifResult'], function(index, value) {
  $('.notifMenu').append('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + value['id'] + '" class="notifi"><i class="' + value['icon'] + ' text-purple "></i> ' + value['notificationText'] + '</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work either... What I am trying to achieve is when clicked on a <li> it will display the data-id of that li

Comment: Ok, was editing with a reason why this wasn't going to work, give me 2 minutes

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that I had all of that on the <i>! :s

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the class name 'notifi' from the `<ul />` to make the jQuery pattern work.  See this fiddle for a working example with your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/fng33ogr/1/

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Should be:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu notifi">
```

**Update**

Query changed to be `ul.notifi a`, moved `id` data attribute to `a`.  See latest fiddle.

Comment: What exactly should that fiddle do? Right now all it returns is an undefined object.

Comment: But this way, it won't get the value of the data-id of the notification which I click, I get "undefined"

Comment: So your initial question was the click event wasn't working.  I've changed the code (see fiddle) so that now the query selector for the click has included the `<a />` and now the data-id attribute is on this tag.

Comment: @MasterYoda see recent comment, the OP's question was that the click event wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('click', '.notifi', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log('clicked');
  alert(id);
});
```

to be more specific add parent selector as ul and child selector class as ".notify"